# Can't handle an element from the DOM

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dom

Can someone help me understand, how I can select or type something in this field on а Selenium webdriver with Python?
I used all the paths, wait commands, and also the JavascriptExecutor, nothing helps.
(https://www.linkedin.com/)

[image: field]

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Comment: I've handled it from Firefox DOM and used it for Chrome. 
But is there no way to handle it from Chrome DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below solution:

```
driver.get ("https://www.linkedin.com/")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='search__placeholder--search search-input']").click();
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='JOBS']//input[@placeholder='Search job titles or companies']").send_keys("Type here")
```

Comment: Basically its a button you need to click on that button first and after that you can enter any keyword to search companies.

Comment: What do you think about this?
I've taken the Xpath from the DOM in Firefox (//button[contains(text(),'Find jobs, people, and more')]) and run a webdriver for Chrome and that worked too. 
Is it also a useful and good idea?

Comment: Yes, Contains method is used to find web elements with partial text match.